Raspberry Pi 5 screen showing incorrect colors after reboot
Having an odd issue with all DPI displays on a Raspberry Pi 5. As you can see in the image, the colors are completely wrong on the physical screen (right) compared to the VNC viewer (left).
The standard color bars should show the same colors on both displays, but the screen is displaying different colors - for example, the red bar is showing as orange, and the magenta appears as purple.
Everything was working fine initially, but this started happening after a few reboots. I haven't made any changes to the configuration. I've tested with a couple other displays I have around and they all show the same incorrect colors on this Pi, so it seems to be a system-wide issue rather than a problem with one specific screen. Interestingly, when I tested the same HyperPixel 4.0 on a different Pi 5, the colors displayed normally, which suggests the issue might be with this specific Pi unit.
Has anyone encountered this issue or knows how to fix it? Could it be a driver issue or perhaps a hardware problem with this specific Pi 5?





research linux color space

It's not that far apart, other than the background -- it would be much better if you explained how this image is generated (besides the fact that it's the standard color bars) Is it just a jpeg or .png? If so, does it use a transparent background?

Pursuant to that, I'd bet if you made the alpha of the color bars a little less than 1.0 w/ the green background this would account for the magenta -> purple and red -> orange.

The image is a JPEG, and generally starting from the terminal screen, before loading the UI system, black is still green. I will add some photos to the post for that. Thank you for the suggestions.

@goldilocks check the rest of the screenshots

"seems to be a system-wide issue rather than a problem with one specific screen. Interestingly, when I tested the same HyperPixel 4.0 on a different Pi 5, the colors displayed normally, which suggests the issue might be with this specific Pi unit." -> Strongly implies some connector or hardware on that Pi is broken; you mention other Pi 5's where it works, if you switch the SD cards that would demonstrate software is not the issue.

Yes, I tend to believe so as well. I was only hoping there would be something software/profile related I am not aware of. I appreciate your replies, @goldilocks
